# Working with JWT Authentication for wordpress rest API and getting [jwt_auth] ip_blocked"

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, api, jwt

I am working with JWT Authentication. My code is working very fine. the problem is because I am using it to authenticate user login, I have to test severally if the code is working well. Because of the multiple ajax call, my IP seems to have been blocked. Anyone know how I can unblock and continue working. Waiting for 24hours will delay men. The website is mine.  see the error on Postman

```
{
    "code": "[jwt_auth] ip_blocked",
    "message": "You have exceeded maximum login retries<br /> Please try after 24 hour(s)",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

Comment: please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) and why it is usually counter productive to do so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about how to circumvent the security measures of an unkwown website

Comment: @jps It's my website... I am working on an app to log users in from a mobile app. I have done that successfully. But while I was testing my code. I supposed I made too many calls while testing the conditions in my code. It says I have to wait for 24hours to be unblocked. I am working with POSTMAN to test my Ajax call...and thanks for the observations on the use of the word Urgent

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error message:

> Please try after 24 hour(s)

You may contact the service provider you are trying to login with JWT, but I guess that won't help. Usually they are doing this for a good reason.

Comment: Thanks @Axel Amthor, I am coding an app for my Wordpress woocomerce website. While working on the client side code. i had to test for several conditions resulting to many ajax calls atsame time. previosly i get the 15min wait time. but now i have to wait for 24hours before i get back to work